# iOS: If my app goes into the inactive state, what happens to pending delayed perform selector requests?

Tags: ios, nsrunloop

My hunch is that perform selectors that had been started with afterDelay values > 0.0 and that had remaining time on them when the app went into background will not execute in the background, but will resume with their clocks running down after the app comes out of background mode.

But is my hunch correct?

Answer (score 1):

It honestly depends on what you're delaying.  I've had delayed selectors with animations that jumped into place when the app was foregrounded (is that a word?).  But then with downloads, it finished them up.  And with mathematical functions, they usually finished by the time the app was backgrounded, but I would assume your app wouldn't just leave anything hanging.  Hopefully it would either just finish or cancel the selectors.  And if all else fails, and you are genuinely worried about stopping them yourself, just use the

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:foo selector:bar object:moof];
```

Comment: Well... Yes.  It should in theory because cancelPreviousRequests cancels all requests sent to the target.  Try it out, I've never done nil arguments in the selector field before.